# Sencha filter data from store

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am a new user of sencha touch

I have this store

```
Ext.define('Final.store.Fotos',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: ['Final.model.Foto'],
config:{
    model: 'Final.model.Foto',
    storeId: 'Fotos',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type:'ajax',
        url: '../../../prueba/index.cfm',
        reader:'json'
    }
}
});
```

A model

```
 Ext.define('Final.model.Foto',{
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config:{
    fields:[
        {name: 'caja', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'foto_id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'id_caja', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'foto', type: 'string'}
    ]
}
});
```

And a controller

```
Ext.define('Final.controller.controladorCaja',{
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
    stores: ['Cajas', 'Fotos'],
    models: ['Caja', 'Foto'],

    refs: {
        cajaLista: 'list'
    },

    control: {
        cajaLista: {
            itemtap: 'clickCaja'
        }
    }
},

clickCaja: function(series, item, evento, caja){
    var idcaja = caja.data.caja;
    var vista = Ext.getCmp('principal');
    vista.push({
        title: ' Fotos',
        items : [{
            extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
            config: {
                id: 'fotos'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'fsf'
            }]
        }]
    });
}
});
```

And in my database, I have 2 tables one with `cajas` or `boxes` and other with images that are relational by the `id_caja` or `id_box`

So, in other view into sencha, I show the name of the boxes in a `xtype: list`. So, my question is when I click on an item of the list and function `clickCaja` is fired, get the id of the element clicked and filter the images by the id box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your foto-list shows all fotos by default and should be limited to a specific 'caja' if one is clicked you could use the [built in store filter](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy).

```
var idcaja = caja.data.caja;
Ext.getStore('Fotos').filterBy(function(record, id){
   return record.data.id_caja == idcaja;
}, this);
```

**Edit:**
If you are using a default `Ext.tab.Panel` you can switch between tabs using the setActiveItem method to switch between tabs.

**Example:**

In your main view

```
Ext.define('App.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'main',
    id : 'mainpanel', //set an id for your tab panel
    ...
}
```

In your controller:

```
refs: {
  ...,
  mainPanel :'#mainpanel' //get a reference to the main panel
},
```

In your eventhandler you could then use something like...

```
this.getMainPanel().setActiveItem('fotoList'); //fotoList = xtype of your foto view
```

... to switch to your foto-list.

Comment: Thanks very interesting, but for example how can i change between views if i have fotos view and principal("main") view, in principal i have the controller and then it loads store (cajas) and model (caja) then with a itemtap i want to get the id of the item and go to the other view "fotos" and filter (just show me the fotos of that id caja)

Comment: I added a solution to switch between two tabs. Assuming that you are using a tab panel with two tabs where your first tab shows the cajas and the second tab shows the fotos. If you want to show "cajas" only in your tab panel you could just create (Ext.create) the foto-list-panel and add it to the viewport.